# I can't sort a column from highest to lowest or vice versa but the rest of the columns can

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 columns:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3
111111     111111        1
222222     222222        2
333333     333333        3
444444     444444        4
555555     555555        5
666666     666666        6
```

If I click on "Column1" or "Column2", the table is correctly ordered from least to greatest.
But if I click on "Column3" it doesn't.

The code works fine, but when I have more numeric data ie. "1" and "11" sorts the number "11" as one. Example. It orders me 1, 11, 14, 15, 2, 3, 4...

This is my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('th').each(function (columna) {
        $(this).click(function () {
            let registros = $('table').find('tbody > tr').get();

            registros.sort(function (a, b) {
                let valor1 = $(a).children('td').eq(columna).text().toUpperCase();
                let valor2 = $(b).children('td').eq(columna).text().toUpperCase();

                return valor1 < valor2 ? -1 : valor1 > valor2 ? 1 : 0
            });

            $.each(registros, function (indice, elemento) {
                $('tbody').append(elemento);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

All data is recovered from database as `string`, and I tried to convert "Column3" in `int` but nothing happens

Any solution for that?

Comment: You're comparing values as text, coerce them to integers and then compare them

Comment: I tried to convert them in the controller but it doesn't work

Comment: You need to convert them in your JS where you make the comparison, because `text()` returns a string: `let valor1 = parseInt($(a).children('td').eq(columna).text().toUpperCase(), 10);`, and do the same for `valor2`

Comment: Ok, I will try it and if I correct it will post the answer, thanks! I have very low level with Javascript, I'm practicing